Find a lost movie with a bit of a Christmas theme about girls with a truck that collects teeth in exchange for money
I'm looking for a live action film of which I only remember a few scenes; I can't remember the year or the actors. It's a film with a bit of a Christmas theme, there's a counter before December 24.
There's a young girl with a bobbed haircut, I think. She's part of a kind of group of girls of all ages who use a truck to exchange money for the teeth of children who have lost some, using a pipe connected to the truck which is used as a means of transport and a means of exchange, the pipe slips under the child's pillow and sucks out his tooth and in exchange he gets a ticket, it's like a tooth fairy job. There's also a scene in which several of the girls climb into the truck and leave the factory in an elevator carrying the truck.
There's a scene where a young girl eats a sandwich while listening to music on some kind of old machine, and because of this, a young man's room is filled with money, and it has glued his bed to the ceiling. The next day, he has to find a way to hide the money and hides it in some kind of garage.
There's also a car chase with some bad guys, and in the end, the three kids go up the stairs and find Father and Mother Noel. That's all I remember, and I may have mixed up a few memories, but I've been looking everywhere for years, and that's really my last solution.

https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5062/tips-for-asking-movie-tv-identification-questions

A girl with a square? A square what?  What kind of square? She uses a truck to exchange money for teeth?  Does she give teeth and get money? Or does she give money to get teeth?   In what way does the truck participate in the exchange?  Did you mean to say trick?   This is a confusing description.

it's a girl with bobbed hair, the truck is a means of transport to carry young women to exchange teeth, it's like a job for a little mouse. It's a bit of a blur because I don't remember it very well, I was young.

This is Tooth (2004). It was set around Xmas, had a Tooth Fairy heroine with an adorable bob haircut and featured a truck that collects teeth (and money) using a long hose.

"Tooth" tells the story of a feisty young Tooth Fairy who lives in a
world called Fairytopia that has lost its ability to use magic. Fed up
with the way most fairies have forgotten about magic, she decides to
give away all of its money and bankrupt her world, two days before
Christmas. When she realises how much trouble she is in, she realises
the only person who can help is the legendary Mrs. Santa Claus, who
disappeared, along with magic over 100 years ago. Teaming up with two
human children and a number of fairies who are living incognito among
humans, she sets off on the adventure of a lifetime, pursued by the
evil, terrifying fairy Plug.




